# Python TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, math

I have a list of random generated numbers between -pi/2 and pi/2 and I calculate the sin function for every point in that list. All works fine until I want to do something with the list. I try to print it simply it works... but if I try to add something or apply another function to the list I get the error

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(0, 10000):
    onenumber = random.uniform(lowerBound, upperBound)
    x.insert(i, onenumber)
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    sinuses = math.sin(x[i])
print(abs(sinuses[0]))
```

Comment: What do you expect to get from `sinuses[0]`?

Comment: And as a hint you do not need put `0` in first of the `range`, it will begin from `0` as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you wanted.

```
import math
import random

lowerBound = -math.pi/2
upperBound = math.pi/2
x = []
for i in range(10000):
    onenumber = random.uniform(lowerBound, upperBound)
    x.insert(i, onenumber)

sinuses = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    sinuses.append(math.sin(x[i]))
    print(abs(sinuses[i]))
```

Comment: OP will just copy and paste your code with don't really understand whats going on , try not to put whole code here , just explain what is the problem and what can he/she do to solve it.

Comment: Thanks.. I was completely blind about the fact that I was assinging values to sinuses like it was a variable and not a list... I need to replace my eyes